# How do i get all picklist values from a field in salesforce using REST Api?

Tags: jquery, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I am trying to get all picklist values from a field in salesforce using REST API. Is it possible to do that? If it is then how it can be done?

Thanks,

Raj.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's very simple. You need to access resource similar to this: `/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Opportunity/describe` (use whichever object you want) and the JSON response will contain `fields` node:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to request a single field values rather than all object fields with values?

Comment: Seems like I sorted it out myself, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72885081/2551398