# Salesforce - how can I search for all Opportunity custom fields that are empty (never been populated) for every Opportunity record?

Tags: salesforce

I need to search for any opportunity's custom field that are empty for every record, so that I can delete those fields that are not used by the users. Can I do this by report or by DevConsole, with some query?

Comment: I have no idea about..cause the problem is not to find all the record that match with a criteria, but rather all the fields that are never filled , for any record of Opportunity..

Comment: How can I query for field rather than for record, by SOQL? How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are three options that would work best:

1. **Data Loader**

   Use their Data Loader to export all of your opportunities into a CSV.  Load it up in Excel or some other software of your choice and manually dig through the columns ending in `__c` looking for at least one value.
2. **SOQL**

   You could manually write a SOQL query that looks at each field (e.g. `SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE YourCustomField1__c != null` and repeat for each field)
3. **SOQL (Dynamic)**

   If you're willing to get your programming hands dirty you could make a [describe API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231878/how-do-i-get-all-picklist-values-from-a-field-in-salesforce-using-rest-api) call to fetch all the fields on the opportunity object.  Once you know all the fields you could find fields that end in `__c` again and write a dynamic SOQL statement to hit the API with.

Answer (score 0):

The Field Trip app (free in the AppExchange) will do this for you.  Here's a link:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4

Run it for an object and it gives you a report that lists all the field and tells you what % of records are filled in for each field.  My organization has been using it for several years now.

I'm not connected with Qandor.  I'm just a satisfied user.