# How do i get all values from a global pick list in salesforce using REST Api?

Tags: rest, salesforce

I know i can get the values of the picklist via a call to describe  [an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231878/how-do-i-get-all-picklist-values-from-a-field-in-salesforce-using-rest-api).

1. Is it possible to get the values without adding the field to an object and to query the values regardless of the object it is used in?
2. Is it possible to do the same with GlobalValueSets? According [to the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_globalvalueset.htm) they are used since API 38.0 and later.

Answer (score 2):

Since API 39.0 it is possible to access [GlobalValueSets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_globalvalueset.htm) through the Tooling API. It is possible to access the GlobalValueSet without adding the field to an object.

The following REST call should be used:

> GET /services/data/v39.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet/{ID}

Where the ID can be found in SalesForce > Global Value Set > The Global Value Set you wish to access via the API > Grab the ID from the URL.