# Salesforce object describe has big data, how to get limited data like picklist values from salesforce object describe

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am looking for way to get fields and picklists for a salesforce object. I can do it with a REAT API call using `/describe` after the object name. But sometimes the returned JSON data is really big with 95% extra data I don't want, with repetitive pattern strings.

This would be too inefficient to pull all that data, which could actually be as large as 2.8Mb, just to get small info I require.

How can I query query filter this data to get more specific results? Or is there a better way to get picklists for a field, or any other sub data from that big json at `/describe`?

Here is what I am using currently

`https://[myinstance].salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Casedata/describe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query [`FieldDefinition`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm) table in Tooling API, for example

`/services/data/v52.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Metadata+FROM+FieldDefinition+WHERE+EntityDefinitionId+=+'Account'+AND+QualifiedApiName+=+'Status__c'`

```
(...)
"valueSet" : {
        "controllingField" : null,
        "restricted" : true,
        "valueSetDefinition" : {
          "sorted" : false,
          "value" : [ {
            "color" : null,
            "default" : false,
            "description" : null,
            "isActive" : null,
            "label" : "Prospect",
            "urls" : null,
            "valueName" : "Prospect"
          }, {
            "color" : null,
            "default" : false,
            "description" : null,
            "isActive" : null,
            "label" : "Live",
            "urls" : null,
            "valueName" : "Live"
          }, {
            "color" : null,
            "default" : false,
            "description" : null,
            "isActive" : null,
            "label" : "Cancelled",
            "urls" : null,
            "valueName" : "Cancelled"
          }
(...)
```

The picklist values will be in the `Metadata` field but to query it you need to ensure only 1 row is returned. So if you need 3 picklists - that's 3 API calls...

It'll return the "master" picklist, not filtered by record type.

There's also interesting table called [`PicklistValueInfo`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_picklistvalueinfo.htm). It's not described too well, it's a related list to `EntityParticle`. You can query to get multiple picklist values in 1 go

```
SELECT DurableId,EntityParticleId,IsActive,Label,Value 
FROM PicklistValueInfo
WHERE EntityParticle.EntityDefinition.DeveloperName = 'Account' AND 
(DurableId LIKE 'Account.Industry%' OR DurableId LIKE 'Account.Type%')
ORDER BY DurableId
```

[image]

Or use it related list style (which might be closer to results of describe call?)

```
SELECT DataType, FieldDefinition.QualifiedApiName,
    (SELECT Value, Label FROM PicklistValues)
FROM EntityParticle 
WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName ='Account'
    AND QualifiedApiName IN ('Industry', 'Type', 'Status__c')
```

---

If you use **record types** - UI API David linked to is easiest.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_picklist_values_collection.htm

You can grab them all

/services/data/v52.0/ui-api/object-info/Account/picklist-values/012...

[image]

Or build links like shown on the screenshot to get data for single field.

Answer (score 1):

The only other API that *might* be applicable to your use case is the [UI API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/), which is intended to provide the information a client would need to render the UI for a record or object. For example, the [Get Object Metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_object_info.htm) endpoint might (or might not) suit your needs. Its response body is also not particularly small.

You cannot filter describe data. You're already using the smallest-scoped version of that API.

Answer (score 0):

If you are puzzled which `recordTypeId` to use in [UI API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_picklist_values.htm) query you can try `012000000000000AAA` as specified in this [sample request](https://www.postman.com/salesforce-developers/workspace/salesforce-developers/request/12721794-7c09d9e2-a722-4b7a-9eda-d3bc82ad0c72)

> Record type Id. Use `012000000000000AAA` as default when there are no custom record types.

Works well in my case where I do not have Record Types created.