# Query Salesforce to return picklist values (SOQL?)

Tags: salesforce, middleware, soql

I need to query a Salesforce object to return all possible picklist values for a particular field on that object. We will then use these values to write some conditional logic to handle potential data transformations as we accept incoming data through our middleware (Tray.io).

Any thoughts on how to return these values? Thank you!

Comment: (shameless plug) Does this answer your question? [Salesforce object describe has big data, how to get limited data like picklist values from salesforce object describe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68689165/salesforce-object-describe-has-big-data-how-to-get-limited-data-like-picklist-v)

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to retrieve the values of a particular picklist field within APEX then you can use the following code. The below snippet displays the Lead Source picklist field values in the debug logs within Salesforce. Using this pattern, you should be able to retrieve the values you're looking for and do what you need to with them. Hope this answers your question :).

```
List<String> pickListValuesList = new List<String>();
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Contact.LeadSource.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistValues = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    for( Schema.PicklistEntry pickListVal : picklistValues){
        string value = picklistVal.getValue();
        System.debug('value: '+value);
        }
```

Comment: The original question specifically asked for an SOQL solution.